# PHP Issue with move_uploaded_file in Chrome

Tags: php, file, upload, move

I have a problem with the move_uploaded_file function in Chrome.

It works flawless in IE. Here is the uploading script(upload.php):

```
<?php
session_start();
include "./global.php";


    $res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id='".$_SESSION['uid']."'");
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
    $userid = $row['id'];
    $targetFolder = "/var/www/picturebox/albums/$userid/";

    $tempFile = $_FILES['Filedata']['tmp_name'];
    var_dump($targetFolder.$userid."_");
    move_uploaded_file($tempFile,$targetFolder.$_FILES['Filedata']['name']);

?>
```

The HTML:

```
<input type="file" name="file_upload" id="file_upload" />
```

The function that reads the HTML:

```
$(function() {
    $('#file_upload').upload({
        'uploader' : 'upload.php'
    });
});
```

Any idea of why it doesn't work in Chrome? In Chrome it moves the file to "albums" and in IE it moves the file to albums/userid

Comment: Chrome does not see this server side code. Can you post the html/javascript that requests this PHP script? And how do you set the uid in `$_SESSION['uid']`?

Comment: I updated the first post. The $_SESSION['uid'] is set when you login. Just $_SESSION['uid'] = $row['id'] and $row['id'] is picked up with a simple mysql SELECT.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is i had this problem last week this is a new script and you call it over ajx then you get a new session or a wrong session. Try to send the session_id with the php ajax request and set the session on the other side.

you can send the session_id over a parameter.

```
$(function() {
    $('#file_upload').upload({
        'uploader' : 'upload.php?sid=<?php echo session_id(); ?>'
    });
});
```

You have to write the actual session id to your script. You can set the a javascript variable in your script and use then in the javascript this is the second posibility.

in your PHP script:

```
session_id($_GET['sid']);
```

then its shure that you use the same session. I hope its working.